# POSTING DATA TO A WS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to post new data to a ws but im geting error each time 
I need to

1-pass a username and password each time

2-code the data with AES256 WITH THE API KEY

Code:

```
- (IBAction)AddTicket:(id)sender {


         [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    NSURL *URL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://dev.enano-tech.com/api/Ticket"];

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1",@"id",@"1",@"idProject",@"1",@"idTicketType",@"nameo",@"name",@"nameo",@"description", @"1",@"idStatus",@"2016-06-23 15:20:49",@"creationDateTime", nil];

    NSData *dataToPost = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
     NSData *final =[dataToPost AES256EncryptWithKey:@"02b6e206868660a0d59d2e51a11fdcd6"];
  //
    NSLog(@"postData1e == %@",final);
     NSLog(@"final %@",dataToPost);

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [request addValue:@"CURLAUTH_BASIC" forHTTPHeaderField:@"CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH"];


    [request addValue:@"Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW5hZG1pbg==" forHTTPHeaderField:@"authorization"];

    [request addValue:@"admin:adminadmin" forHTTPHeaderField:@"CURLOPT_USERPWD"];

    [request addValue:@"true" forHTTPHeaderField:@"CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER"];

    [request addValue:@"false" forHTTPHeaderField:@"CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER"];

    [request addValue:@"POST" forHTTPHeaderField:@"CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUES"];

    [request addValue:@"true" forHTTPHeaderField:@"CURLOPT_POST"];

    [request addValue:@"false" forHTTPHeaderField:@"CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS"];

    [request setHTTPBody:final];

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        NSString *result = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:final encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"data  %@",data);
        NSLog(@"respoce  %@",response);
        NSLog(@"result == %@",result);
     }];

    [postDataTask resume];
}
```

Response:

2016-08-02 15:06:47.768 Projector[3936:1619429] result == {"error":"invalid API query", "message":"'data' is not correctly encoded for method POST. Request for correct API KEY"}

this is the documentation of api:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6h40O.png)

Comment: My guess, is that the value you have to post could look like `{"data": "myAESENCRYPTEDData"}`

Comment: You are missing any of the key which is defined in POST method on backend.

Comment: i add all the keys now im having this error

2016-08-02 11:30:18.220 Projector[3175:846154] result == {"error":"invalid API query", "message":"'data' is not correctly encoded for method POST. Request for correct API KEY"}

Comment: It may be because some key don't have to be encrypted, but the values YES, as I suggested beforehand?

Comment: yes but im just encrypting the data?

Comment: is it possible that the API KEY im using is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Your webserver is missing "data" from the website. To fix it, you'll need to add that field to your form or find the correct field name (case sensitive)